# when selecting the datasource it is not showing properly

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to see the datasource that was added previously. but while trying to see..there is not any configure data source option..how to get it.. my screen shot is below. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN: Configure Data Source Dialog Box - SqlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247297%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)